# Get list of blobs in container added after some date

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to read blobs from a azure container which are added after a particular date. 
Basically, I have a windows service which runs once a day and gets the list of blobs added after the first run.
I do not see any such option in CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync function or via the Get Blob REST API call.
I could think of only one option- have timestamp in the filename and filter by prefix but would like to know other better options to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's very limited server-side filtering available in Azure Blob Storage and only filtering allowed today is by blob name prefix.

One solution to your problem is list all blobs in a container. Each blob has a property called `Created Date/Time` which tells you when the blob was first created (there's another property called `Last Modified` as well).

When you have the list, you can filter on the client side by this Created Date/Time property to get the desired list of blobs.